# I want to delete IAM users with a script which have a prefix “vault-” to them and are not the latest created users

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-iam, aws-cli

So I want to keep the latest created users and deleted all other which have "vault-" append to them.

Either with json or text output

```
for users in $(aws iam list-users | jq '.Users[] | select ( .UserName | startswith("vault-") ) | .UserName' | tr -d '"')

do

aws iam get-user --user-name $users | jq '.User | .CreateDate'| tr -d '"'

done
```

How do I query it with date created and then filter with not the latest users?
I want to get a list of all the users but the latest one.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Steampipe](https://steampipe.io) to query AWS resources using SQL:

```
select * from aws_iam_user
where name like 'vault-%'
-- newest first, oldest last
order by create_date desc
-- skip the first (newest) one
offset 1
```

Steampipe output can be piped to other shell commands to perform the deletion you want. For example:

```
steampipe query --output csv --header=false "select name from aws_iam_user where name like 'vault-%' order by create_date desc offset 1" | xargs -I@ aws iam delete-user --user-name @
```

WARNING - That's a deletion script (as requested), be careful!